# Dynamic column selection and apply conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a following data (Table 1):

```
**name | Product1_abc_value | Product2_abc_value**
  lmn  |                 12 |                 20
```

Here Product names are dynamic and number of products as well are dynamic. I have another set of data using which I want to apply a flag. Example (Table2);

```
**Product                 | Cutoff_Value**
Product1_abc_value_Cutoff | 15
Product2_abc_value_Cutoff | 17
```

Using the table above, I wanted to derive a flag based on condition on Table 1 (specific product). Like if cutoff for product1 is 15 then set flag as "1" else "0" for each name.

How should I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to match column names of `tbl1` and `Product` column in `tbl2`. Get `tbl1` in long format and remove `"_Cutoff"` from `Product` column and join the two tables. You can then assign 1 if `Cutoff_Value` is greater than `value`.

```
library(dplyr)

tbl1 %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = -name, names_to = 'Product') %>%
  right_join(tbl2 %>%
               mutate(Product = sub('_Cutoff', '', Product)), by = 'Product') %>%
   mutate(flag = as.integer(Cutoff_Value > value))


# A tibble: 2 x 5
#  name  Product            value Cutoff_Value  flag
#  <chr> <chr>              <int>        <int> <int>
#1 lmn   Product1_abc_value    12           15     1
#2 lmn   Product2_abc_value    20           17     0
```

**data**

```
tbl1 <- structure(list(name = "lmn", Product1_abc_value = 12L, 
Product2_abc_value = 20L), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-1L))

tbl2 <- structure(list(Product = c("Product1_abc_value_Cutoff", 
"Product2_abc_value_Cutoff"), Cutoff_Value = c(15L, 17L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: This works perfectly for give example. Thanks. Just one problem, Product1 and Product2 are sample product names. In the actual data they can be any (and not start with string 'Product'). How should I handle that?

Comment: Nothing changes with that right? The point is to match columns of `tbl1` with that of `Product` column in `tbl2`. In the example you shared there was `"_Cutoff"` part which was extra which I remove using `sub`. There is no dependency here that a product name should start with `"Product_"`.